# Why can't Jericho parser parse this HTML code?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

I use jericho parser in my application to get a lighter version of a web page, extracting some parts from it. So, for instance, when I get this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN/" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html> <head> </head> <body> <b> <span class="articletitletext">Happy New Year!</span></b> <br> <span class="postedstamp">Posted By <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> <!-- document.write('<a href="&#32;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#99;&#104;&#114;&#105;&#115;&#46;&#119;&#121;&#109;&#97;&#110;&#64;&#118;&#101;&#114;&#105;&#122;&#111;&#110;&#46;&#110;&#101;&#116;">'); // --> </script>Chris</a> on January 1, 2012</span><br> <br> <span id="intelliTXT">

From all of us here at TheForce.net, we wish you and your family a safe and Happy New Year. May the Force be with you in 2012!

</span></body> </html>
```

I'd like to parse it once again using jericho parser, but when I run

```
ArrayList<Element> centerElems=(ArrayList<Element>) pageSource.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.CENTER);
```

I got this exception

```
01-01 10:46:37.518: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(648): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.test.theforce/net.test.theforce.NewsListActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$EmptyList
```

and the application crashes...so, what's wrong with the lighter page?

Comment: You should post the exception, otherwise it's a whole lot more difficult to figure out...

Comment: Updated with the error message taken from logCat

Comment: Do you not get a stack trace of any kind or do you just get exactly what you pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the Jericho parser can parse the HTML you gave it.  The error you're getting arises because you've made an incorrect assumption about what the `getAllElements()` method returns.

I admit I could only find the Javadoc for the [zero-argument overload](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/Source.html#getAllElements%28%29) of this method, as opposed to the one-argument overload that you're using, so I'll have to assume that both methods return the same type, `List<Element>`.  In your example, there are no `center` elements in the HTML, so the `getAllElements()` method should return an empty `List<Element>`.  It doesn't have to return an `ArrayList<Element>` here; any implementation of `List<Element>` will do.  In this case, it chooses to return a [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29).  This isn't an `ArrayList<Element>`, and you get a `ClassCastException` because you cannot cast this to an `ArrayList<Element>`.

As far as I can see, you have two options:

- Firstly, you might not need the returned list to be an `ArrayList<Element>`.  It might be sufficient to use `List<Element>` instead.  In this case, you should replace the line

  ```
  ArrayList<Element> centerElems=(ArrayList<Element>) pageSource.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.CENTER);
  ```

  with

  ```
  List<Element> centerElems = pageSource.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.CENTER);
  ```
- Secondly, if you really do need the list to be an `ArrayList<Element>`, then you can create an `ArrayList<Element>` from the results:

  ```
  ArrayList<Element> centerElems = new ArrayList<Element>(pageSource.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.CENTER));
  ```